# What does R0/R1/R2/R3 stand for when referring to Robertson square screwdriver?

Tags: screwdriver

I cannot find anywhere on the net what do these R0, R1, ... markings mean, sometimes they're referred as sizes, but then the detailed dimensions of an R1 and R2 screwdriver are listed as exactly the same.

Comment: Whoever listed that was wrong; there is much bad information on the web, sadly, and some employees of reputable companies copy, paste and forget to change things, without adequate editorial oversight or proofreading. There's some overlap, since they are tapered, but they are definitely different sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Look at Table 1 in [this reference](http://www.aspenfasteners.com/v/vspfiles/files/docs/square_drive_specification.pdf), it gives the minimum and maximum dimensions for the square based on the screw sizes.  The maximum allowed dimensions of the square are as follows (including my conversion to mm):

| Drive Label | Max inch | Max mm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0710 | 1.8 |
| 1 | 0.0910 | 2.31 |
| 2 | 0.1126 | 2.86 |
| 3 | 0.1330 | 3.38 |
| 4 | 0.1910 | 4.85 |

Answer (score 2):

The R0, R1, etc, refers to the bit or tip size. If you have  Phillips head screw drivers you may notice the tips are different size, #0 being small, #2 being larger. Individual tips are usually 1/4" hex drive.